# How to create signed apk from cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

HI i am working on cordova project and i was able to create signed apk from my cordova project. but now i updated my cordova,ionic,android studio etc... when i try to create signed apk it is not working o am getting debug.apk file only below i am giving the result

```
:preBuild
:preReleaseBuild
:checkReleaseManifest
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preBuild
:CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild
:CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareReleaseDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseJava UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedReleaseLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:prepareReleaseDependencies
:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:compileReleaseJava UP-TO-DATE
:lintVitalRelease
:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:preDexRelease UP-TO-DATE
:dexRelease UP-TO-DATE
:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:packageRelease UP-TO-DATE
:assembleRelease
:cdvBuildRelease

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 13.243 secs
Built the following apk(s):
    /Users/faitu/builtest/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk
Administrators-MacBook-Pro:builtest munafwew$
```

Answer (score 0):

for signed cordova apk first you need 

keytool.exe - to make .keystore file for your apk.

then run command on command prompt 
keytool --genkey -v -keystore `<name of file .keystore>` -alias `<some name>` -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 99999

and follow the steps to create keystore for your app.

now use jar signer to sign your app.
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -d
igestalg SHA1 -keystore `<path of keystore file created above>`   `<path of unsigned apk>` `<output file name apk>`

Comment: Hi thanks for your replay. Where i need to create the keystone file inside the outputs file?

Comment: basically .keystore file is made parallel to you app main folder,